# Is there any way to add identifier or tag custom event added in iCal?

Tags: iphone, calendar, icalendar, eventkit, reminders

I am setting a reminder in my app. I have added a custom event using `EKEvent` to `iCal`. Now when I retrieve events from `iCal` I get all the events present on that day. Is there any way to get/retrieve events added through my app only, I tried `eventIdentifier` property of `EKEvent` but it is a readonly property.
Can anybody help???

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through all of the calendar events that match a specific date but that is not the preferred method. Each event is created with a unique eventIdentifier property. When you save the event you can copy the eventIdentifier and next time you want to modify that specific event you can use the EKEventStore eventWithIdentifier Method to load your Event.

A sample might look like this

> ```
>    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
>    NSError *err;
>    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
>    //modify all the event properties you would like then save
>    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
>    self.calendarEventID = event.eventIdentifier; 
>    [eventStore release];
> ```

Later if you want to retrieve the saved event from the previous code you could do the following

> ```
>    //self.calendarEventID is a NSString property declared in the .h file and synthesized in .m
>    EKEvent *myEvent = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:self.calendarEventID];
> ```

Comment: I would recommend not relying on the event identifier! As taken from the EventKit class `EKEvent.h`

_Please note that if you change the calendar of an event, this ID will likely change. It is currently also possible for the ID to change due to a sync operation. For example, if a user moved an event on a different client to another calendar, we'd see it as a completely new event here._

Answer (score 1):

Kludge:

I had a similar problem with an AppleScript I made for setting iCal alarms; I wanted to be able to identify and delete the events my script had made on the next pass.

I couldn't find any tag-like properties for iCal events, so I ended up using the location property, which is a string; I set it to " " and searched for that. (Caveat: The alarm message includes the location at the end, surrounded by parens, so this glops things up a bit.)

If you need the location property for other purposes in your app, you still might be able to add some identifying character sequence. Or maybe you can use some other property you don't otherwise need.